# Render correct partial view with ajax call

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, partial-views

I have a controller with partial views, for example I have a partial view , like this:

```
[HttpGet]
        [AutorisatieFilter(Rol = "Personeelsdossier | Rekeningen@Lezen")]
        public ActionResult Rekeningen()
        {
            var model = PersoneelsDossierService.GetRekeningLezenModel(Context, HuidigeDienstverbandId,GetMutatieRol(), Gebruiker.DienstverbandId);

            SetMedewerkerSelectie(model);

            model.IsBevoegd = true;

            try
            {
                BeveiligingService.ControleerManagerBevoegdheidVoorDienstverband(Context, Context.Klant.Id, int.Parse(Context.Gebruiker.ExternId), HuidigeDienstverbandId, Gebruiker.DienstverbandId);
            }
            catch(AuthenticationException)
            {
                model.IsBevoegd = false;
            }

            return PartialView("~/Areas/MSS/Views/PersoneelsDossier/Rekeningen.cshtml", model);
            //return View(model);
        }
```

This is inside the controller name: Personeelsdossier.

The view of Rekeningen looks,like this:

Answer (score 0):

Partial Views do not use the Layout, so they will not include CSS unless you have the CSS in the partial view - They are intended to be render **into** full views.

Just change the Partial View to a full view if you want to use the layout page, or add your CSS to the Partial View if you want the CSS but no layout...

Comment: Thank you for your answare. But what do you mean with full views? Can you give an example? thank you YOu mean just this: return View(model);

Comment: @thecodeEngine - Yes indeed, View() will use the layout page (which is probably where you have your CSS etc defined)

Comment: @thecodeEngine - PartialView and View have no difference in performance... The only difference is that View will put the contents of the view into the Layout page combined. If you need to add all the stuff from the layout page into your partial view anyway then they will have exactly the same performance. What gave you the impression this will help with performance? If you insist on using a PartialView - simply copy the CSS link tags into the partial view...

Comment: oke, But, I have some performance issues. So what I have to change then? Thank you

Comment: @thecodeEngine - I imagine it is something in your Controller Action (Rekeningen), but I only understand english so can't really follow what it is doing... is it hitting a database for the data? Probably I would start there

Answer (score 0):

In our Application, we have special Master pages for Partial Views to include Scripts and CSS for example.

1) Create a new Master Page cshtml in `Views\Shared` folder (for example, `PopupMaster.cshtml`). It holds a very basic HTML template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link href="~/Content/some.additional.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    @RenderBody()

    <script src="maybe.some.additional.script.to.execute.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

2) Instead of `return PartialView(...)` you can now do `return View("MyView", "PopupMaster", myModel);`

This will result in a partialview-like result, but with possibility to provide extra css and scripts